# How to validate html form for null/empty fields with JavaScript using ID assigned to form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I'm trying to validate my html form with JavaScript as so it iterates trough out all input fields and checks for empty/null fields.

I found a way to validate for null on w3s (code below) but I want to modify the function as so it checks for all fields on the form using a specific `id` that I have assigned to the entire form, instead of only targeting one field.

```
function validateForm() {
   var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
   if ( x == null || x == "" ) {
      alert("First name must be filled out");
      return false;
   }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 19):

As well as these I would include the `required` attribute, just incase users have javascript disabled.

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" required/>
```

It works on all modern browsers not the older ones though as it is part of HTML 5

Comment: I like this option however I noticed that when the required input field was within a tabbed accordion element (so within an element that is hidden and revealed with javascript) it had a hard time switching to the tab with the required field to indicate that it was the required field along with the tooltip the browser provides, however, when the tab is active the tooltip displays correctly...

Comment: what if the field is optional?

Answer (score 2):

```
function validateForm(formId){
    var form=document.getElementById(formId);
    for(i=0; i<form.childNodes.length; i++)
        if(form.childNodes[i].tagName!='INPUT'||
           typeof form.childNodes[i].value=="undefined")
            continue;
        else{
            var x=form.childNodes[i].value;
            if(x==null||x==""){
                alert("First name must be filled out");
                return false;
            }
        }
}
```

Not sure if it works.

Comment: I will. let me test (:

Comment: @irm my code never gets executed. Clicking "submit" results in "doCheck is not defined". I think you don't know javascript and what's going on in jQuery. So please, don't use it. `document.getElementById('checkme').onsubmit=function(){var formId='checkme'; /* here goes my code in function validateForm */ }`

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since you posted this question, but since you haven't accepted an answer, here's a simple solution: ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qaiser110/BHXvb/))

```
function Validate()
{
    var msg= "",
        fields = document.getElementById("form_id").getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (var i=0; i<fields.length; i++){
        if (fields[i].value == "") 
            msg += fields[i].title + ' is required. \n';
    }

    if(msg) {
        alert(msg);
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: excellent answer, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

give the form an id of "myForm"

then you can select it with:
var form = document.getElementById("myForm");

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest way:

```
<script>
        function validateForm(formId)
        {
            var inputs, index;
            var form=document.getElementById(formId);
            inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
                // deal with inputs[index] element.
                if (inputs[index].value==null || inputs[index].value=="")
                {
                    alert("Field is empty");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
</script>
```

Replace <`form`> tag with the below:

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="1.php" onsubmit="return validateForm('myForm');" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

just put the Required into the input tag then whenever you click the submit button then empty Textbox will give the error field can not blank. 
example:- 
`<input type="text" id="textbox" required/>`

Answer (score 0):

It is important to manage the fact that for some form elements like textareas, the required attribute behaves in Firefox differently from all other browsers. In Firefox whether your input is NULL or empty, the required attribute block the form submission. But in Chrome or Edge, the form will submit on an empty field not on NULL one